# JS clearInterval or window.clearInterval?

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

Javascript has setInterval and clearInterval functions for handling asynchronous function calls.

Is there a difference between `clearInterval(handle)` and `window.clearInterval(handle)`?

I've seen it being used both ways.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In a browser, all global functions are implicitly properties of the `window` object.  So `clearInterval()` and `window.clearInterval()` are the exact same thing.

There is no difference between them unless you define a local function called `clearInterval()`, in which case `window.clearInterval()` would reference the global one and `clearInterval()` would reference the local one.

The same would be true for any global functions that you define yourself.

Answer (score 0):

There is no real difference

This is basically the same as the following where global variable are a properties of the window object.

```
var myvar = "hello";

alert(myvar);

alert(window.myvar);
```

or where global functions are properties of the window object.

```
document.getElementById("myID");

window.document.getElementById("myID");
```

Answer (score 0):

`window` is the global context object. If you are not in a function that has had it's scope modified, everything you type is implicitly preceded by `window.`.

```
var a = 0;
window.a = 0;

setTimeout(foo, 1000);
window.setTimeout(foo, 1000);

alert(this == window); //true
```