# Twitter bootstrap progress bar animation on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page with several bootstrap progress bars. Setting their values initially works fine. Though I would like the progress bars to animate/transition to their specific states when a user opens the page.

This JS works fine, when you click on one of the bars. I would need something like that on an "onload" event of the bar. But the "onload" event is not available for s

```
//animate progress bars
$('.progress .bar').on("click", function(event) {
  var me = $(this);
  perc = me.attr("data-percentage");
  me.css('width', perc+'%');
});
```

How can I achieve this behavior on page load for all progress bars on a page?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

While Tats_innit's answer has a nice touch to it, I had to do it a bit differently since I have more than one progress bar on the page.

here's my solution:

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vacNJ/

HTML (example):

```
<div class="progress progress-success">
<div class="bar" style="float: left; width: 0%; " data-percentage="60"></div>
</div>

<div class="progress progress-success">
<div class="bar" style="float: left; width: 0%; " data-percentage="50"></div>
</div>

<div class="progress progress-success">
<div class="bar" style="float: left; width: 0%; " data-percentage="40"></div>
</div>
```

​

JavaScript:

```
setTimeout(function(){

    $('.progress .bar').each(function() {
        var me = $(this);
        var perc = me.attr("data-percentage");

        var current_perc = 0;

        var progress = setInterval(function() {
            if (current_perc>=perc) {
                clearInterval(progress);
            } else {
                current_perc +=1;
                me.css('width', (current_perc)+'%');
            }

            me.text((current_perc)+'%');

        }, 50);

    });

},300);
```

@Tats_innit: Using setInterval() to dynamically recalc the progress is a nice solution, thx mate! ;)

**EDIT:**

A friend of mine wrote a nice jquery plugin for custom twitter bootstrap progress bars.
Here's a demo:
http://minddust.github.com/bootstrap-progressbar/

Here's the Github repo:
https://github.com/minddust/bootstrap-progressbar

Comment: it works well.. but sometimes it shows the decimal value in the progressbar and the % went away from the progressbar....

Comment: Hi - can someone tell me how to edit this script to make it ten minutes? I have played around but I cant seem to get a ten minute rule - any ideas? Thanks v much

Answer (score 72):

**EDIT**

- Class name changed from `bar` to `progress-bar` in v3.1.1

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="progress progress-striped active">
        <div class="bar" style="width: 0%;"></div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

**CSS**

```
@import url('http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css');

.container {
    margin-top: 30px;
    width: 400px;
}​
```

**jQuery** used in the fiddle below and on the `document.ready`

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var progress = setInterval(function() {
        var $bar = $('.bar');

        if ($bar.width()>=400) {
            clearInterval(progress);
            $('.progress').removeClass('active');
        } else {
            $bar.width($bar.width()+40);
        }
        $bar.text($bar.width()/4 + "%");
    }, 800);

});​
```

**Demo**

<strike>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xXM2z/)</strike>

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5w5ku/1/)

Comment: While this solution is nice for something like a single file download it doesn't work for pages with several progress bar elements like in my case.

Comment: @Alao this might help to understand: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8347248/js-clearinterval-or-window-clearinterval `:)`

Answer (score 19):

Bootstrap uses CSS3 transitions so progress bars are automatically animated when you set the width of .bar trough javascript / jQuery.

http://jsfiddle.net/3j5Je/ ..see?

Answer (score 10):

In contribution to ellabeauty's answer. you can also use this dynamic percentage values

```
$('.bar').css('width',  function(){ return ($(this).attr('data-percentage')+'%')});
```

And probably add custom easing to your css

```
.bar {
 -webkit-transition: width 2.50s ease !important;
 -moz-transition: width 2.50s ease !important;
   -o-transition: width 2.50s ease !important;
      transition: width 2.50s ease !important;
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's a cross-browser CSS-only solution. Hope it helps!

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/tuiaverde/details/KgJbGx/)

```css
.progress .progress-bar {
    -moz-animation-name: animateBar;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    -moz-animation-duration: .4s;

    -webkit-animation-name: animateBar;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    -webkit-animation-duration: .4s;

    animation-name: animateBar;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    animation-duration: .4s;
}

@-moz-keyframes animateBar {
    0% {-moz-transform: translateX(-100%);}
    100% {-moz-transform: translateX(0);}
}
@-webkit-keyframes animateBar {
    0% {-webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);}
    100% {-webkit-transform: translateX(0);}
}
@keyframes animateBar {
    0% {transform: translateX(-100%);}
    100% {transform: translateX(0);}
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  
  <h3>Progress bar animation on load</h3>
  
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width: 75%;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```