# Javascript Countdown with Twitter Bootstrap Progress Bar

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am working with the Twitter Bootstrap. I need to redirect the page after 30 seconds. I want to use the Twitter Bootstrap Progress Bar to indicate how long till the page redirects (So the page redirects when the bar is at 100%). Please could someone help me with the Javascript and HTML code to do this.

Thanks ;)

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/q/10007212/434171

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Very basic example:

```
var bar = document.getElementById('progress'),
    time = 0, max = 5,
    int = setInterval(function() {
        bar.style.width = Math.floor(100 * time++ / max) + '%';
        time - 1 == max && clearInterval(int);
    }, 1000);
```

Code wrapped in function:

```js
function countdown(callback) {
    var bar = document.getElementById('progress'),
    time = 0, max = 5,
    int = setInterval(function() {
        bar.style.width = Math.floor(100 * time++ / max) + '%';
        if (time - 1 == max) {
            clearInterval(int);
            // 600ms - width animation time
            callback && setTimeout(callback, 600);
        }
    }, 1000);
}

countdown(function() {
    alert('Redirect');
});
```

```css
body {padding: 50px;}
```

```html
<link href="//getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="progress">
    <div class="bar" id="progress"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, really awesome! Could you just tell me how to make the page reload when the countdown gets to zero?